# Copying files from a android phone without display or touch

Tags: backup, broken-screen, oxygenos, oneplus-x

My Oneplus X phone fell and the display and touch are not functional anymore. When I connect to my Linux laptop, an empty "Android" drive and "OnePlus X drivers" drive gets mounted. I tried copying the contents, but been unsuccessful. Is there a way to get the contents?

Comment: The only possibility I see is buying a new touch display (may be a cheap display from China) and connect it (temporarily) to the phone.

Answer (score 0):

You could trying plugging in a mouse to your device via an OTG cable. Then you should be able to access your notifications bar and configure your phone to communicate with the PC.

Comment: Using a mouse in "blind mode" (without a working display) will be very very difficult.

Comment: Ahh I didn't spot that - good point.